Why Doesn't the cooling system on a rocket engine burn the fuel?
The cooling system on a specific rocket engine is usually a type of "pipe" that goes around the nozzle to not only keep the nozzle cool but also pre-heat the fuel. But the nozzle can reach thousands of degrees in heat. So why doesn't this ignite the fuel?

"… pre-heat the nozzle" You probably mean "pre-heat the fuel"?

To a layman like me, the words "cooling" and "heating" seem to be used quite confusingly here.

@Vilx-, It's pretty simple. When you use "cool" and "heat" as verbs, you are talking about removing thermal energy from something (cooling it) or adding thermal energy to something (heating it). If you're talking about a continuous process, then there does not have to be any change in temperature. E.g., a computer's CPU could be continuously heated by the electricity that it uses, and continuously cooled by flowing air, and all the while maintaining a constant temperature. The pipe that wraps a rocket nozzle continuously cools the nozzle while continuously heating the fuel.

@Ohm'sLawman Ahh, ok, got it!

It's inside a pipe with no air, oxygen, or another oxidizer.
The fuel in the cooling channel is contained, it's not exposed to air or oxygen. As such, it can't ignite. There's no way for it to burn.
What can be a problem is that when cooked in the absence of oxygen, some fuels can make soot, gummy varnish, or other solid material that could plug the cooling channel. Proper cooling system and fuel chemistry engineering is needed to prevent this -- one of the features of RP-1 rocket grade kerosene is that it is resistant to polymerizing when heated in a cooling channel.

"cooked" I prefer to think of it as "roasted" to bring out its robust flavor

@uhoh I'm pretty sure the chemists fixed that too. I'm pretty sure some of them even tasted the resulting cooked/roasted fuel to make sure.

@uhoh - I prefer fuels with overtones of hickory and chocolate when roasted. Sadly, my small-batch boutique roasting rockets don't get very far off the ground.

@JonCuster Forget rocket scientists, the real money is in a rocket fuel sommelier career.

Sometimes the channel does get gummed up, which can even result in the channel partially melting - but when that happens it's not gummed up anymore!  It seems crazy, but that situation can exist in equilibrium.

I'd add to the answer that there's a good reason the fuel is generally what's used for cooling. It might seem more intuitive to use the oxidizer because we're surrounded by air and it seems like fuels are more dangerous, but actually it's rather the oxygen that's the highly reactive part of a combustion process - and it will combust also stuff that you didn't want to oxidize. Making metal parts that withstand hot oxygen is very challenging, whereas it's easy to make them withstand hot fuel.

@uhoh Charles Stross reveals that rockets were actually invented in order to produce the perfect brew ... "Herr Von Braun, perhaps best known as the architect of the A4 rocket, is particularly enthusiastic about the prospects of using cryogenic hydrogen-oxygen motors as a combination roasting/grinding and percolation technology." :-)

@MindwinRememberMonica Rocket fuel sommelier seems like the kind of job that can explode into a career, but it seems like such sommelier careers would be quite short, huffing those fumes!

@leftaroundabout Being surrounded by air, water and oils, my intuition is that fluids are more suitable for cooling than air due to their higher heat capacity. On the other hand, that intuition does probably not extend to cryogenic substances…

@Bergi well, air is less suitable for cooling than kerosene because it has a much lower density. But for the same reason it's also infeasible to store gaseous air as the oxidizer for a rocket. With liquid fuels, the immense mass flow means that either kerosene or hydrogen or oxygen can do the job of cooling the nozzle, from a heat capacity perspective. You choose whatever has the least risk of eating away the nozzle. Water would be the best choice in terms of cooling capacity - but that's neither very good as a fuel or oxidizer!
